# Is there any way that I can share my iPhone Application for testing without having a developer account?

Tags: ios, testing

I was trying to share my application for testing and I don't currently have an AppStore paid account. My client was asking me to find if there any way exist to send the application for testing without having a paid developer account. Please help me with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There a a LOT of tricks, but I think 99$ for a regular account will make you save a LOT of time (and money) avoiding hacking.

With a paid account you can:

- send an IPA directly to customer
- use TestFlight even without registering mail/devices
- test up to 100 devices.

a question: can you have physically near the customer device?

Comment: No. I don't. He actually is in another country. Could you please tell me one good way to send the application?

Comment: I think REALLY will be cheaper to get a dev account. You will save a huge amount of hours.

Comment: and of course you customer does NOT own a Mac..

Comment: Okay. As I was asked this by my client, I was forced to look for a solution. Even I like to use the proper method. Thank you for your time.

Comment: as a last resort, simply say it will take a day ... so you will be paid for.. and buy ADC account with that money.. :)

Comment: You have no idea how much we get paid in India. 

Comment: I am sad, but your customer is NOT correct: you should have a minimal set of tools.